# How to do distributed tracing with newrelic for spring boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic, newrelic-platform, distributed-tracing

We can enable distributed tracing on newrelic.yml file as below

```
distributed_tracing:
   enabled: true
```

But the interservice tracing is not available,
Do we need to do any changes on spring boot application side.

Comment: What's newreilc agent version in server?

Comment: @user7294900 its newrelic-java-4.11.0

Comment: what do you mean by interservice?